# Postgresql connection limit parameter is equal to a negative number

Tags: postgresql

I can't quite understand why the connection limit property of a postgresql database has a negative one value.

What does a connection limit of -1 means?

Comment: do you mean `max_connections`?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation of the [`pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html) catalog:

> `datconnlimit`     `int4`     Sets maximum number of concurrent connections that can be made to this database. -1 means no limit.